# HTTP cross-domain request responsed with 400, but server do receive request data

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, server, cross-domain

I send a HTTP cross-domain `POST` request using Ajax in Chrome 43 to a server that have the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, and Chrome log a message in devtools as follow:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://172.65.34.13/v1/image/upload. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:6032' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

And the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.9.4
Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 02:05:46 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 105
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: sessionid=39b9608771e38408b2f1278621805514; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

But the most weird thing is the server do receive my post data! How it could be like that? Did I miss something about the request or the server? Can anybody help me fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server **does not** know if the request is from an AJAX or not, so it will always receive the post data. But the browser blocks the response body and returns you a 400 bad request.

In your case, there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in the response header. There must be something wrong with your server.

Comment: It turned out to be browser block the response to script, got it, thanks :) But the server do set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, and we use `nginx + go` to set up server, any idea for that matter?

Comment: @huachengzan Maybe you can follow this guide: http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html . It works for me.